# Transitions run slower on first use in IE

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I have an element that has `transition: all .25s linear;`.

It runs very slightly slower on its first use whenever the page is loaded in IE11, and thereafter works as expected. Why is this? Is there some caching of the animation? Works as expected in Chrome.

This sounds nitpicky, but it's a noticeable and annoying glitch as the elements position is effected by it, and on the slower load, you can see a background element you shouldn't be able to.

Comment: You could serve us an working example so we can reproduce and see it ourselfs.

Comment: `transition: all` is not perfomant. You should limit this to just the properties than need it.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Yeah, tried limiting it to just width and margin-left (which is what actually changes), still the same effect. Also, it runs find on every transition except the first, which is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that it runs slowly the first time due to initial page load. There may be other processes running that may slow the transition down too. The second time will be smoother because resources have been cached and performance isn't hampered. I would run your site through https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/?hl=en to find any render-blocking scripts that may be hampering performance.

Also see this article to identify which properties can be animated cheaply. 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/